# Create Defect Using OTA API

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center

I am trying to add a new defect in QC using OTA API. I am unable to set some mandatory fields while defect creation. Below is my code.I am using .NET framework 4.5 and C# for code development.

1. There is a problem with Issue Type field, constant used for Issue Type is BG_USER_02 
   If I set value to this Issue Type constant it shows error as "Required field  can not be empty or SPACE filled" even though I already set value for status as bug1.Status = "New"

If I commented Issue Type that is 
  //Issue Type
  //bug1["BG_USER_02"] = "Defect";
It gives error as Required field  can not be empty or SPACE filled.;

2. Also Please tell me constant(eg.BG_USER_02) value used for following mandatory fields that is Issue Type, Product, Application & Module are correct or not If these are not proper constant values please suggest me constant values for these fields.

   ```
       //Issue Type
       bug1["BG_USER_02"] = "Defect";

       //Product
       bug1["BG_USER_07"] = "Product1";

       //Application
       bug1["BG_USER_08"] = "Application";

       //Module
       bug1["BG_USER_04"] = "Accounts";


   string qcUrl = "http://localhost:XXXX/qcbin";
       string qcDomain = "TestDomain";
       string qcProject = "TestProject";
       string qcLoginName = "user1";
       string qcPassword = "user1";
       TDConnection connection = new TDConnection();
       connection.InitConnectionEx(qcUrl);
       connection.ConnectProjectEx(qcDomain, qcProject, qcLoginName, qcPassword);
       BugFactory bugFact = connection.BugFactory;
       Bug bug1 = bugFact.AddItem(System.DBNull.Value);
      //Summery
       bug1.Summary = "This is summary";

       //Detected in Cycle
       bug1["BG_DETECTED_IN_RCYC"] = @"Release\Program\Test\Value";

       // Detected in Release
       bug1["BG_DETECTED_IN_REL"] = @"Release\Program\Test\Value";

       //Issue Type
       bug1["BG_USER_02"] = "Defect";

       //Product
       bug1["BG_USER_07"] = "Product1";

       //Application
       bug1["BG_USER_08"] = "Application";


       //Module
       bug1["BG_USER_04"] = "Accounts";

       //Priority
       bug1.Priority = "P1 - High";

       //Severity
       bug1["BG_SEVERITY"] = "SEVERITY1";

       //Lines of Business
       bug1.Project = "Fire";


       //Reproducible
       bug1["BG_REPRODUCIBLE"] = "Y";

       // Owner Name
       bug1.AssignedTo = "XYZ";

       //Status
       bug1.Status = "New";

       //Detected By
       bug1.DetectedBy = "user1";

       //Detected on Date
       bug1["BG_DETECTION_DATE"] = "9/9/2016";

       //Detected in Version
       bug1["BG_DETECTION_VERSION"] = "8.1.0.11";

       //Description
       bug1["BG_DESCRIPTION"] = "Description";

       bug1.Post();
       MessageBox.Show("Post");
       connection.DisconnectProject();
       connection.Logout();
       connection.ReleaseConnection();
   ```

Thanks
Amrapali Kamble

Comment: Please be more specific when asking questions. What have you done so far? What is working? What error do you get? Where in your code are you stuck?